# ListView with text searchbox and images to filter record from Sqllite

Tags: android, sqlite, android-listview

I had written following function

```
 Cursor cursor1 = db.fetchAllRecord();
        String[] columns = new String[] {
                "DATE","ID","NAME","AMOUNT","PHOTO"}

        };

        // the XML defined views which the data will be bound to
        int[] to = new int[] {
                R.id.date,
                R.id.ide,
                R.id.name,
                R.id.amount,
                R.id.imageView_round,
        };


        dataAdapter = new AlterCurAdapter(getActivity(),R.layout.list,cursor1,columns,to);
        // Assign adapter to ListView
        listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

In above code fetchAllRecord(),fetch all record.Now i want to display only DATE,ID,NAME,AMOUNT,PHOTO of each record so i add column name to string array.

But PHOTO is of type BLOB.So i am getting error cannot convert BLOB to String.So what should i do as i want to display image of record which is of blob type

Comment: any example or link please

Comment: see: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder.html